# Duplication Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Consider the SQL query below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT shops.*, 
       DA.delivery_cost, 
       DA.postcode 
FROM shops 
       JOIN shops_delivery_area as DA on DA.shop_id = shops.id 
WHERE DA.postcode = "Liverpool" 
      OR location = "Liverpool"
```

`shops` table

```
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
| id | name     | location  | postcode |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Shop One | Liverpool | L10      |
|  2 | Shop Two | Liverpool | L16      |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
```

`shops_delivery_area` table

```
+------------------+---------+----------+---------------+
| delivery_area_id | shop_id | postcode | delivery_cost |
+------------------+---------+----------+---------------+
|                1 |       1 | L10      |          0.00 |
|                2 |       1 | L11      |          0.00 |
|                3 |       1 | L12      |          1.00 |
|                4 |       1 | L13      |          1.00 |
|                5 |       2 | L10      |          0.00 |
|                6 |       2 | L16      |          0.00 |
|                7 |       2 | L28      |          0.00 |
+------------------+---------+----------+---------------+
```

User can search by Postcode (eg: `L14`, `L15`, `L16`) or Location from a textbox.

If user type in "Liverpool", it will find all the shops that are located in "Liverpool".  The problem is there will be duplicate rows of shop name (shops table). How to solve this issue?

**Result (Search by Location):**

How to avoid duplication of shop name?

I should do: `shops.id = shops_delivery_area.shop_id AND shops.postcode = shops_delivery_area.postcode`

```
+----+----------+-----------+----------+---------------+----------+
| id | name     | location  | postcode | delivery_cost | postcode |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+---------------+----------+
|  1 | Shop One | Liverpool | L10      |          0.00 | L10      |
|  1 | Shop One | Liverpool | L10      |          0.00 | L11      |
|  1 | Shop One | Liverpool | L10      |          1.00 | L12      |
|  1 | Shop One | Liverpool | L10      |          1.00 | L13      |
|  2 | Shop Two | Liverpool | L16      |          0.00 | L10      |
|  2 | Shop Two | Liverpool | L16      |          0.00 | L16      |
|  2 | Shop Two | Liverpool | L16      |          0.00 | L28      |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+---------------+----------+
```

**Result (Search by Postcode L10):**
Work fine as expected

```
+----+----------+-----------+----------+---------------+----------+
| id | name     | location  | postcode | delivery_cost | postcode |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+---------------+----------+
|  1 | Shop One | Liverpool | L10      |          0.00 | L10      |
|  2 | Shop Two | Liverpool | L16      |          0.00 | L10      |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+---------------+----------+
```

Comment: add group by on the basis of shop name.

Comment: @GauravVashishtha Look the query carefully, I have `DISTINCT`

Comment: DISTINCT is different from GROUP BY. DISTINCT returns only distinct rows (all values must be different) and GROUP BY returns rows which have distinct values on the fields you group by.  For example, grouping by shopname, will show only rows with distinct shopname. But beware that for the delivery_cost and postcode fields, you should use an AGGREGATE function, e.g. the MAX(delivery_cost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get it working. I have used UNION to solve this problem.

```
SELECT U.* FROM 
   ((SELECT DISTINCT shops.*, DA.delivery_cost, DA.postcode AS AreaPostcode FROM shops
             JOIN shops_delivery_area2 as DA on DA.shop_id = shops.id
   WHERE DA.postcode = "Liverpool")
  UNION
   (SELECT DISTINCT shops.*, DA.delivery_cost, DA.postcode AS AreaPostcode FROM shops
             JOIN shops_delivery_area2 as DA on DA.shop_id = shops.id AND DA.postcode = shops.postcode
   WHERE shops.location = "Liverpool")) as U
```

If there anyway to make this code shorter or improve it, let me know. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the "Result by Location" you have "delivery_cost" and "postcode", as long as these are different you will always get "duplicates" remove those two and you'll only see one of each.

Edit:
If you need those fields as well filter on them on the default value the shop should have. If you need all the results from "delivery_cost" and "postcode" but only one result you should rethink what it is you are trying to do or explain what result it is you expect.

Comment: Yes I understand that but I need those two fields.

Comment: @user791022 so what values should delivery_cost and postcode contain when there are duplicates like in the example you provided?

Comment: @AdityaNaidu When searching by Location, It should use `shops.id = shops_delivery_area.shop_id AND shops.postcode = shops_delivery_area.postcode`

Comment: @Joakim When searching by Postcode, it work fine without duplication. However whens searching by Location - it should do `shops.id = shops_delivery_area.shop_id AND shops.postcode = shops_delivery_area.postcode`

Comment: @user791022 of course it works when you search by Postcode since each shop only has the same Postcode ONCE which makes it unique and only return one result for that shop, however MULTIPLE Postcodes for the same shop SHARES ONE Location which is why you get more results. (i'm not angry, only trying to make the important words stand out)

Comment: @Joakim I have just posted my answer, please see and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT shops.*, 
MIN(DA.delivery_cost), 
MIN(DA.postcode) 
FROM shops 
JOIN shops_delivery_area as DA on 
       (DA.shop_id = shops.id AND shops.postcode = DA.postcode)
WHERE DA.postcode = "Liverpool" 
      OR location = "Liverpool"
GROUP BY shops.location, shops.name, shops.id, shops.postcode
```

Comment: When searching by Location, It should use `shops.id = shops_delivery_area.shop_id AND shops.postcode = shops_delivery_area.postcode`

Answer (score 0):

matching the postcode from both the tables will give you distinct shop names when searched by location.
something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT shops.*, 
       DA.delivery_cost, 
       DA.postcode 
FROM shops 
       JOIN shops_delivery_area as DA on (DA.shop_id = shops.id  and DA.postcode = shops.postcode)
WHERE DA.postcode = "Liverpool" 
      OR location = "Liverpool"
```